# Visual Studio and Yocto Linux Cross compile

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cross-compiling, yocto

I am trying to set up visual studio for remote Linux build for Yocto and encountered some strange problem.

I have installed yocto SKD on WSL and modified PATH variable to contain path to the compiler by default (via ~/.bashrc file). So my PATH variable looks like:

```
echo $PATH
/opt/poky/3.0.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/poky/3.0.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/sbin

:/opt/poky/3.0.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/bin:/opt/poky/3.0.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/sbin:

/opt/poky/3.0.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/../x86_64-pokysdk-linux/bin:/opt/poky/3.0.2/

sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux:/opt/poky/3.0.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/

bin/x86_64-poky-linux-musl:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:

/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

And when I run compiler I get proper response:

```
x86_64-poky-linux-gcc
x86_64-poky-linux-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

However, Visual Studio can not see the compiler.

I have added a pre-build event in which the PATH Variable is printed and the PATH from Visual Studio does not contain my modifications:

```
1>  Task "Execute"
1>    Task Parameter:IntermediateDir=C:\Users\SINSIN\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\obj\x64\Debug\
1>    Task Parameter:RemoteProjectDir=/home/sinsin/projects/ConsoleApplication3/
1>    Task Parameter:ProjectDir=C:\Users\SINSIN\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\
1>    Task Parameter:RemoteTarget=-988202288;127.0.0.1 (username=, port=2222, authentication=Password)
1>    Task Parameter:Command=echo $PATH
1>    Task Parameter:RequireRemoteConnection=True
1>    Task Parameter:Timeout=7200000
1>    Invoking 'echo $PATH', working directory: '/home/sinsin/projects/ConsoleApplication3/'
1>    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
1>  Done executing task "Execute".
```

Could you tell me what is the proper way to WSL and Visual studio for such a project?

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved the problem by modifying PATH variable in /etc/environment file.